# @Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function inside volley

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to fetch an api data by Volley connection and assign into Text Composable, but it didn't work and showing error:

> @Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function

I know that There is a similar question but it didn't solve me my problem

how can i solve this error?
because I'm New in Jetpack compose

CODE:

```
@Composable
fun getJSON() {
val context = LocalContext.current
val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context)
val url = "https://adeega.xisaabso.online/android.php"



val stringRequest = StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
{ response ->

  val jsonObject = JSONObject(response)
  val TotalMoney = jsonObject.get("Total")

  Text(text = "$TotalMoney")

},
{
  Toast.makeText(context, "Welcome to Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
})
queue.add(stringRequest)

}
```

SetContent

```
setContent {
  First_JetpackCompose_appTheme {
    // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
    Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colors.background) {

      getJSON()

    } // END Surface
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You **can't** use `Text(text = "$TotalMoney")` in the `response` block.

Use a `ViewModel` or just use something like:

```
var totalMoney by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

Text(text =  totalMoney)

val stringRequest = StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
{ response ->

  /* Your code */
  totalMoney = ....

},
{
  Toast.makeText(context, "Welcome to Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
})
queue.add(stringRequest)
```

Comment: Mr Mariotti, this code does not work, can you complete the code inside response request?

Comment: totalMoney = jsonObject.get("Total")